# How to reply with 200 from Nginx, without serving a file?

Tags: nginx, http, html

I have configured Apache to send back a 200 response without serving any file with this configuration line

```
Redirect 200 /hello
```

Can I do this with Nginx? I don't want to serve a file, I just want the server to respond with a 200 (I'm just logging the request).

I know I can add an index file and achieve the same thing, but doing it in the config means there's one less thing that can go wrong.

Comment: One could argue that if you don't serve a "file" or any content, you should return 204 No Content, as opposed to 200.

Answer (score 489, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
location / {
    return 200 'gangnam style!';
    # because default content-type is application/octet-stream,
    # browser will offer to "save the file"...
    # if you want to see reply in browser, uncomment next line 
    # add_header Content-Type text/plain;
}
```

Comment: how do I add a newline to the response? `gangnam\nstyle`?

Comment: @tback of course, right you are

Comment: Just add the newline! Nginx configuration directives are not bound to single lines, they are ended by semicolon.

Comment: add_header doesn't work for me as it adds another header instead of replacing the old 'Content-type'. In my response I have 2 'Content-type' headers:$ curl -v localhost/healthcheck/h1_pio 
> GET /healthcheck/h1_pio HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2016 13:27:53 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 25
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: application/json

Comment: @jmcollin92 
your comment has nothing to do with the question that was asked and to which the answer was given.

because you obviously have some sort of proxy_pass, fascgi_pass, whatever...

but I still answer

    location /healthcheck/h1_pio {
        # proxy_pass blablabla what you need;
        proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
        add_header Content-Type application/json;
    }

in the future, ask your question correctly and in the proper location

Comment: @jmcollin92 that can happen if you have an existing default_type declared somewhere else. You can override it by using `default_type text/plain;` inside of the location block in place of the `add_header` directive.

Comment: This is awesome for adding health checks to a dedicated reverse proxy instance! `location /health { add_header Content-Type text/plain; return 200 'healthy'; }`

Comment: Hint: use `add_header Content-Type text/plain always;` to force plain text if you're not returning a "successful" code.

Comment: If you have authentication enabled, take care that this doesn't bypass it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447376/auth-basic-within-location-block-doesnt-work-when-return-is-specified

Comment: Worth to mention this post: http://www.nginxer.com/records/how-to-configure-nginx-to-return-text-or-json/

Comment: This will return a unformatted text. If that is the point of the answer, ok. But if the objective is to return a formatted html page, this doesn't work. An edit was not accepted for the answer, regarding such improvement, so I provided a different answer, with a broader scenario.

Comment: In case you need to return a custom 404 page with a custom `Content-Type` header but can only append part of the Nginx configuration (Kubernetes ingress-nginx controller configuration), please see my answer below.

Answer (score 53):

If you want to return a **formatted HTML text**, without serving a HTML file:

```
location / {
    default_type text/html;
    return 200 "<!DOCTYPE html><h2>gangnam style!</h2>\n";
}
```

If you want to return a text **without html format**, as the answer points:

```
location / {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 'gangnam style!';
}
```

And if you just simply wants to return 200:

```
location / {
    return 200;
}
```

Just to remember: `location` blocks go inside `server` blocks. Here's a [doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more information about the topic.

P.S.: I have similar configuration (formatted html) running on plenty of servers.

Comment: Also it's nice to add: `charset: utf-8;` to display non-latin characters correctly

Answer (score 33):

You do need to use a 204 as Nginx will not allow a 200 with no response body. To send a 204 you simply use the [return directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule#return) to `return 204;` in the appropriate location.

Comment: If you try to view this through a browser, it will look like it did nothing. that's intentional.  You served nothing (204), it displays nothing.  To prove you served a 204, use `curl`.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that nginx will not allow 200 with no content? I’ve read several examples from other people saying it works.

Comment: @ElliottB the answer was made 13 years and many nginx version ago. It indeed works now.

Answer (score 8):

To complete @Martin Fjordval's answer, be careful if you're using such a configuration to do a healthcheck.

While a `204` HTTP code is semantically perfect for a healthcheck (success indication with no content), some services do *not* consider it a success.

Namely, I had the issue with [Google Cloud Load-balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks).

Comment: Exactly. Google Cloud Load Balancer **requires** a 200 response code to consider the instance healthy, no matter the body. Any other code (even 2xx codes) will make the health check fail.

Answer (score 6):

As per status code definitions, I believe you want it to be a 204, and not 200.  200's need to be with a resource in the response, or I'd suspect most sane browsers would get confused by this.  The other one you can use is 304, which is for cached content.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Sure, make it a 204, how do I do it? Although I very much doubt any browser will be confused by an empty body.

Comment: an empty body is still a response, with an object, such as a blank index.html.  What you asked is to provide a 200 response with no resource attached to it (no file served).  As for how exactly to do it on nginx, I need to look it up myself, I've only once done this on apache, and I can't remember off hand.

Comment: 304 seems like it would send all the wrong signals for things like debugging and temporary returns.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the @cadmi answer for a specific case of Kubernetes ingress-nginx controller configuration.

In my case, I could only append the small part of the Nginx configuration inside the `location` directive.

I wanted to add a custom 404 error JSON message for a specific `if` directive. Since `default_type` is not allowed inside the `if` directive I came up with adding the "blank" `default_type` outside the `if` directive and `add_header` inside the `if` directive:

```
http {
    default_type text/html; # can't change this
    ...
    server {
        ...
        location / {
            ...
            # This part of configuration is something I can change (generated by ingress-nginx controller `ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` annotation)
            default_type "";
            # Custom 404 JSON page returned for the call to my.specific.host
            if ($host = my.specific.host) {
                return 404 '{\n  "status": "404",\n  "message": "Not Found",\n  "details": "Please call other hosts."\n}\n';
                add_header Content-Type "application/json" always;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without the `default_type "";` an `add_header` directive was adding the second `Content-Type` header instead of changing the default one.

Comment: If you have `nginx-extras`, `openresty` or similar, you don't need `default_type "";` - just use `more_set_headers 'Content-Type: text/plain';` - plus `return 900 'blubbi'`.