# Can I use nginx environment variables within static files that nginx serves?

Tags: nginx, docker, environment-variables, static-content

If I use a environment variable in the nginx config, and nginx is configured to serve only static files (html,js,css - e.g. a AngularJs app), is there any way I can use the environment variable within a JS file that nginx serves? Or is the only way to do this to run a non-static server, e.g. io.js, php, etc.

---

> Btw you can't use environment variables natively in nginx's configuration.

When I talk about environment vars in the nginx config I mean like in this post: [How can I use environment variables in Nginx.conf](https://serverfault.com/questions/577370) where they use `env APP_WEB_1_PORT_5000_TCP_ADDR;` and `$ENV{"APP_WEB_1_PORT_5000_TCP_ADDR"};`

---

> Explain exactly your use case

My specific use case is that I have a nginx-powered AngularJS app in a docker container. The app is a "Single Page Application" that consumes a API running on another system altogether. Currently I run a different docker container between production and staging because the app has some config that is different, for example the Google-Analtyics code. This environment-specific data is kept in a `config.js` file and the values are currently hardcoded, one value for the `master` branch in git, and different value for the `staging` branch. I want to change the design so I can use **the same** container for both production and staging. I want to pass a ENV var into the container when I run it (`docker run -e GACODE=UA-12345-6 ...`) and have nginx use the ENV var (via `env GACODE;` and `$ENV{"GACODE"}` so the `config.js` file can use the GoogleAnaltyics codes that are passed in, rather than hardcoding them). I don't know whether this is possible or not (hence the question ;)). Using only nginx makes my container a single-process, whereas if I have to use io.js then I'll need multiple linked containers and more moving parts is more complex).

Comment: What ?! Explain exactly your use case since it appears you are looking at it on the wrong side. Btw you can't use environment variables natively in nginx's configuration.

Comment: Thanks @XavierLucas - I updated the question to try to explain more.

Answer (score 9):

I've been looking into resolving the same issue as the OP and this post came up in Google search, so thought I'd add a potential solution.

This post outlines how you can expose an environment variable within nginx config: https://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/environment-variables-in-nginx-config/

And you can return content without having a file in the file system: [Reply with 200 from Nginx config without serving a file](https://serverfault.com/questions/196929/reply-with-200-from-nginx-config-without-serving-a-file)

Putting these two things together we end up with the following:

```
env MY_ENV_VAR;

# Snip

http {
    # Snip

    server {
        # Snip

        location ~ ^/config.js$ {
            add_header Content-Type text/javascript;
            set_by_lua $env_var 'return os.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR")';
            return 200 'const MY_ENV_VAR = \'$env_var\'';
        }
    }
}
```

This has worked for me in a test environment. It's a little cumbersome (not sure it's better than auto-generating a file on Docker launch that contains the vars you need).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

I experimented with using [sub_filter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter) and nginx environment variables but concluded that **it isn't possible**.

For example, this shows my experiments and shows using ENVs passed to nginx does ***not*** work within a `server` block:

```
env TOMTEST1; # OK - makes $ENV{"TOMTEST1"} available but NOT in server block.

http {

    server {

        # set $TOMTEST1 $ENV{"TOMTEST1"};    # KO - DOES NOT WORK - NGINX WONT START
        set $TOMTEST2   'tomtest2 Var';      # OK - THIS DOES WORK OK

        sub_filter 'TOM_TEST2' $TOMTEST2;       # OK - but not useful to me.
        sub_filter 'TOM_TEST3' 'tomtest3 Var';  # OK - but not useful to me.
        sub_filter_once off;                    # Don't stop at the first match, replace all of them
        sub_filter_types "text/javascript" "application/json"; # Apply to these mime types in addition to text/html

        # Serve static files
        location / {
           try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }
        ...
```

where the static config.json file that I'm serving has various test strings like the following:

```
{
    "environment": "local",
    "test1": "$ENV{"TOMTEST1"}",
    "test3": "TOM_TEST2",
    "test4": "TOM_TEST3",
}
```

As @AD7six mentioned, the way to proceed is have a script that runs before nginx starts to produce a valid config file from placeholders. But this begs the question, if a script is going to run before nginx starts, I may as well set the contents of my `config.json` file in that script and not bother with `sub_filter` at all.

Comment: If it's for one static file - it certainly makes sense to not do it via nginx config,  I assumed your usecase was a bit broader than that. For info/contrast I use `sub_filter "example.com" "example.dev";` in a dev setup to replace any and all references to the production domain to the local environment because those references come from 3rd party api responses/app code/js/db dumps/etc. - i.e. for nginx it could be anywhere in any html/js/json response. +1

Answer (score 4):

### sub_filter

If you want a simple string-replace, you can use [sub_filter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter). For example:

```
server {
    sub_filter "REPLACE_THIS" "with this";
    sub_filter_once off; # Don't stop at the first match, replace all of them
    sub_filter_types "text/javascript" "application/json"; # Apply to these mime types in addition to text/html 

    # Everything else
}
```

**However** it's not possible to read an environment variable *in* nginx config - you can of course script writing the nginx config file any way you need/want to produce a valid config file and then reload nginx.